# Authorize Accept suite hosted form not returning failed transaction response

Tags: iframe

We are using the Accept Suite iframe method to integrate the payment form from authorize.net

Everything works well as long as the transaction is successful. For a failed response, the api is not returning action=transResponse to the iframe. IT only returns action=resizeWindow.

we need the failed transaction to direct the user to the right page and also to record the reason for the failed transaction.

Any help?
My settings:

$apiRequestJSONStr = '{
"getHostedPaymentPageRequest":
{
"merchantAuthentication":
{
"name": "",
"transactionKey": ""
},
"transactionRequest":
{
"transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
"amount": "assignAmount",
"order":
{
"invoiceNumber": "paymentId",
"description": "paymentType"
},
"billTo":
{
"firstName": "",
"lastName": ""
}
},
"hostedPaymentSettings":
{
"setting": [
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl",
"settingValue": ""
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentButtonOptions",
"settingValue": "{"text": "Pay"}"
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentReturnOptions",
"settingValue": ""
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentOrderOptions",
"settingValue": "{"show": false}"
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentPaymentOptions",
"settingValue": "{"cardCodeRequired": true, "showCreditCard": true, "showBankAccount": false}"
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions",
"settingValue": "{"show": true, "required": true}"
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions",
"settingValue": "{"show": false, "required": false}"
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentSecurityOptions",
"settingValue": "{"captcha": false}"
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentCustomerOptions",
"settingValue": "{"showEmail": false, "requiredEmail": false}"
},
{
"settingName": "hostedPaymentStyleOptions",
"settingValue": "{"bgColor": "green"}"
}]
}
}
}';

$commUrl = json_encode(array('url' => "$iframeCommUrl"), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$apiRequestData->getHostedPaymentPageRequest->hostedPaymentSettings->setting[0]->settingValue = $commUrl;

$retUrl = json_encode(array("showReceipt" => false, 'url' => "$successUrl", "urlText" => "Continue to site", "cancelUrl" => "$cancelUrl", "cancelUrlText" => "Cancel"), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

In the below image, the first arrow is when the page loads, the second is when the transaction failed, the third is when the transaction was successful.

[image]

Expecting the transResponse action not returned for failed transaction.